# Unable to list deployments resources using RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I am using a x509 authentication for a user in Kubernetes, which works fine.
However, while provide access to the deployments does not seem to be working fine, as shown below:

Roles:

```
# kubectl get rolebindings devops-rb -n demo -o yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-03-26T13:43:49Z
  name: devops-rb
  namespace: demo
  resourceVersion: "2530329"
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/demo/rolebindings/devops-rb
  uid: b6c17e28-30fb-11e8-b530-000d3a11bb2f
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: devops-role
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Group
  name: devops
```

Role Bindings:

```
# kubectl get roles devops-role -n demo -o yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-03-26T13:43:49Z
  name: devops-role
  namespace: demo
  resourceVersion: "2538402"
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/demo/roles/devops-role
  uid: b6bee0fb-30fb-11e8-b530-000d3a11bb2f
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - secrets
  - services
  - replicasets
  - persistentvolumeclaims
  - deployments
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

Trying to list deployments using user config:

```
# kubectl --kubeconfig /root/.kube/config-tesla get deploy -n demo
Error from server (Forbidden): deployments.extensions is forbidden: User "tesla" cannot list deployments.extensions in the namespace "demo"
```

Trying to list deployments  using the admin config:

```
# kubectl  get deploy -n demo
NAME              DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
wordpress         1         1         1            1           13d
wordpress-mysql   1         1         1            1           13d
```

Trying to list pods using user config:

```
# kubectl --kubeconfig /root/.kube/config-tesla get po -n demo
NAME                               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ncp-centos-pod                     1/1       Running   0          12d
wordpress-77d578745-vdgr9          1/1       Running   0          13d
wordpress-mysql-58cf8dc9f9-pzvbs   1/1       Running   0          13d
```

Trying to list pods using admin config:

```
# kubectl  get pods -n demo
NAME                               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ncp-centos-pod                     1/1       Running   0          12d
wordpress-77d578745-vdgr9          1/1       Running   0          13d
wordpress-mysql-58cf8dc9f9-pzvbs   1/1       Running   0          13d
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

replicasets and deployments exist in the "extensions" and "apps" API groups, not in the legacy "" group

try:

```
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - secrets
  - services
  - persistentvolumeclaims
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  - apps
  resources:
  - deployments
  - replicasets
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly..

Check:

```
kubectl describe clusterrole |grep devops-role
kubectl describe clusterrole |grep devops-rb
kubectl describe clusterrole | less
```