# openshift Crash Loop Back Off error with turbine-server

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Hi I created a project in Openshift and attempted to add a turbine-server image to it. A Pod was added but I keep receiving the following error in the logs. I am very new to OpenShift and i would appreciate any advice or suggestions as to how to resolve this error. I can supply either further information that is required.

io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/booking/pods/turbine-server-2-q7v8l . Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked..

Comment: Is your application running in the pod attempting to use the REST API to access OpenShift/Kubernetes? If you are you need to run the application under a service account which has been granted appropriate access. Provide more details on how you are deploying the application and whether it does need to access the REST API.

Comment: Please show the openshit version, the service account and RBAC manifests (role and role binding). https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/admin_solutions/user_role_mgmt.html or https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/

Answer (score 0):

### How to diagnose

Make sure you have configured a service account, role, and role binding to the account. Make sure the service account is set to the pod spec.

```
spec:
  serviceAccountName: your-service-account
```

Start monitoring atomic-openshift-node service on the node the pod is deployed and the API server.

```
$ journalctl -b -f -u atomic-openshift-node
```

Run the pod and monitor the journald output. You would see "Forbidden".

```
Jan 28 18:27:38 <hostname> atomic-openshift-node[64298]: 
logging error output: "Forbidden (user=system:serviceaccount:logging:appuser, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)"
```

This means the service account **appuser** doest not have the authorisation to do **get** on the **nodes/proxy** resource. Then update the role to be able to allow the verb "get" on the resource.

```
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
    - "nodes"
    - "nodes/status"
    - "nodes/log"
    - "nodes/metrics"
    - "nodes/proxy"   <----
    - "nodes/spec"
    - "nodes/stats"
    - "namespaces"
    - "events"
    - "services"
    - "pods"
    - "pods/status"
  verbs: ["get", "list", "view"]
```

Note that some resources are not default legacy "" group as in [Unable to list deployments resources using RBAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495189/unable-to-list-deployments-resources-using-rbac).

#### How to verify the authorisations

To verify who can execute the **verb** against the **resource**, for example patch verb against pod.

```
$ oadm policy who-can patch pod
Namespace: default
Verb:      patch
Resource:  pods

Users:  auser
        system:admin
        system:serviceaccount:cicd:jenkins
Groups: system:cluster-admins
        system:masters
```

#### OpenShift vs K8S

OpenShift has command **oc policy** or **oadm policy**:

```
oc policy add-role-to-user <role> <user-name>
oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user <role> <user-name>
```

This is the same with K8S role binding. You can use K8S RBAC but the API version in OpenShift needs to be **v1** instead of **rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1** in K8s.

#### References

- [Managing Authorization Policies](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/admin_guide/manage_authorization_policy.html)
- [Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/)
- [User and Role Management](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/admin_solutions/user_role_mgmt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hi thank you for the replies - I was able to resolve the issue by executing the following commands using the oc command line utility:

```
oc policy add-role-to-group view system:serviceaccounts -n <project>
oc policy add-role-to-group edit system:serviceaccounts -n <project>
```

Comment: Generally not a good idea to add roles like that to all service accounts in a project via a group, as you are modifying special internal service accounts for your project when you do that.. You should qualify it to just the single service account requiring it. Applications use the ``default`` service account. Better when add ``edit`` or ``view`` to create a new service account with the role and then run your application under that service account. BTW, you don't need both ``view`` and ``edit``. Only use one, and only use ``edit`` if it needs to change things.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Graham I do appreciate it. So i could create a new service account (named "robot" for example) only for edit for my booking project?

oc policy add-role-to-user edit system:serviceaccount:booking:robot

Comment: Yeah, but don't use ``system:serviceaccount:booking:robot``. Run command as ``oc policy add-role-to-user edit -z robot`` in the project. The ``-z`` option ensures correct scope for current project is used. Less error prone that way.